# Parallel Period on SalesVariance MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I created a query which calculates variance level on sales and the percentage on the variance. However, my query returns NULL whenever I try to test against the CostSales measure!

```
IIF(

  IsEMPTY(
            (
            ParallelPeriod
                    (
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],
                    1,
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].CurrentMember
                    ),[Measures].[CostSales]
             )
        )   
OR
             (
             ParallelPeriod
                    (
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],
                    1,
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].CurrentMember
                    ),[Measures].[CostSales]
              )=0
,
0,
[Measures].[ParallelPeriodFactSalesVariance]/[Measures].[ParellelPeriodFactSales]
)
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the name of that calc? What's the definition of [Measures].[ParallelPeriodFactSalesVariance] and [Measures].[ParellelPeriodFactSales]?

Comment: The ParellelPeriodFactSales calculation formula is Sales Amount plus the Parallel Period Internet Sales Amount from the same month 1 year prioR. While the second  [Measures].[CostSales]-[Measures].[ParallelPeriodFactSales]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not getting 0 returned then I'd assume that there is a problem with `[Measures].[ParallelPeriodFactSalesVariance]/[Measures].[ParellelPeriodFactSales]`

Two diagnostics you can run are:

1.Change the whole measure to this:

```
IIF(

  IsEMPTY(
            (
            ParallelPeriod
                    (
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],
                    1,
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].CurrentMember
                    ),[Measures].[CostSales]
             )
        )   
OR
             (
             ParallelPeriod
                    (
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],
                    1,
                    [Time].[CalendarSales].CurrentMember
                    ),[Measures].[CostSales]
              )=0
,
0,
999
)
```

I'd imagine 999 is being returned. If it is then try changing the custom member to just this:

```
[Measures].[ParallelPeriodFactSalesVariance]/[Measures].[ParellelPeriodFactSales]
```

Is `NULL` now being returned? So this is the problem - but as Greg's comment suggests we need to see the code for these two measures - also, as context is important, we could do with seeing the full script where your code is being used.

Comment: I have changed the whole measure as you suggested and it worked. Then, I added the last code: [Measures].[ParallelPeriodFactSalesVariance]/[Measures].[ParellelPeriodFactSales] and surprisingly enough the code has worked like a charm. Thank you much for your answer and thank you Greg for the clarification.

Comment: ok - the above was only meant as diagnostics - happily surprised it worked for you as an answer

Comment: I think the solution didn't deploy the work properly. I implemented the code you sent and then deployed it. Then I altered it to my previous code by changing the last and ran the deployment button and it worked! Thanks again